# How to paint primefaces pie charts with huge legends?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jqplot, pie-chart

I want to paint some pie charts with huge legends, but I can't resize the yellow panel in the background of the pieChart.

Is there any way to resize the yellow panel to put the legend below and not resizing the piechart itself?

Piechart without legend:
[image]

Piechart with legend:
[image]

Here I let you my piechart code (I am using primefaces 4.0):

```
<p:panel style="width: 600px; height:500px;">
    <p:pieChart value="#{pieModel.value}" title="#{pieModel.key}" showDataLabels="true" extender="pieExtender" legendPosition="s" legendCols="6" />
</p:panel>
```

I have tried to play with panel styles, but it was useless.

**EDIT** (after kukeltje comment):

I have searched in jqPlot documentation, but I haven't found anything. What are the jqplot properties for changing this panel size. Or maybe I need an extension?. No idea.Please, show me an example... I just found a way to show labels when moused over, and I figured out it could be something similar, but not come upon the background panel size:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pieExtender() {
        this.cfg.highlighter = {
            show: true,
            tooltipLocation: 'n',
            useAxesFormatters: false,
            formatString: '%s = %d'
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please check jqplot features/extensions etc...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem defining the style of the chart, and I have to calculate how big will be the legend, bring the width and height to the pieChart component:

This is not the best solution, because it is quite impossible calculate the exactly panel size to keep the pie chart size as without legend, but at least I can keep the pie visible...